# Creating site-wide custom list view solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Why is something that seems so simple, so hard to figure out?

I want to create a deployable solution (.wsp) that is simply a custom list view for document libraries.

It should be available for use by all document libraries, i.e., listed in the dropdown list of the ribbon under Library | LibraryTools | Current View.
It must be totally customized, including references to javascript libraries and css stylesheets in the `<head`> tag and `<script`> tags in the body that use jquery and other javascript libraries.
It is a farm solution, not sandboxed, and not ghostable.

It's easy to create a new view in Sharepoint Designer and edit the HTML within the XSLTListViewWebPart.
(Select the webpart, and select List View Tools | Design | Customize XSLT | Customize Entire View)
But a view created here only works with one list and can't be deployed as a .wsp solution.

It's easy to create a visual web part in Visual Studio 2010, but where do you go from there?

This seems like a pretty basic thing that people would want to do, but I can't find any articles or tutorials that explain how.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to have a "one size fits all" list view solution, but you can programatically create list views. You will have to create the list view per list (for each list).

An example on how to [create a list view programatically can be found here](http://sarangasl.blogspot.de/2009/12/create-sharepoint-list-view.html). You will be able to define the HTML (which you probably have designed in SP Designer). The problem with the list view is that it is specific to the list, not all lists have the same columns, hence it will be hard to create something general.

Answer (score 0):

If all the lists that are intended to have the new view have common columns, what you can do is, you edit one list and add you new View in the list, once completed, you can save this list as template (from the settings page) for the new lists. The template is saved as `.stp` file that you can download too. But still there is no Farm wide way(in my knowledge) of generating and deploying such template.